# How does AWS S3 charge for requests? And how is Data Transfer Out size calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-transfer

The pricing @ AWS S3 product page (under the data transfer out to the public internet) states that-

- It's free till 1GB/month.
- Then for **next** 9.999TB/month, the price is $0.09/GB.
- ... (More plans like above)

Does this mean that if I finish my first GB, it will charge me $0.09/GB till 9.999TB/month? It might sound obvious, but still I want to confirm myself. :)

Also, in some case, if I upload a 3mb image to my bucket, and then just 5 people view it. So would it take out 3x5 = 15mb as Data Transfer Out limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

Data Transfer is charged for traffic leaving AWS and going to the Internet. So 5 people viewing a 3MB file would be counted as 15MB.

The cost for Data Transfer becomes cheaper with volume. You are unlikely to exceed 10TB, so just treat it as `$0.09/GB`.